# Ember when does controller reloads? (or reset)

Tags: ember.js

I've noticed that if i use the same controller for different routes it does not get reset so i can keep data shared between routes which is really helpful for me.

But i wonder... when does the controller reloads in ember? (runs the init and cleans all of his properties)?

And can i manually tell the controller to reload itself?

Thanks for the help guys :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The controllers are generally singleton instances (excluding `itemController` instances), they live the life of the page.

If you need to reset some properties you can do it during `setupController` of the route in need.

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    //return something...
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.setProperties({foo:'asdf', bar: 'ewaf'});
  }
});
```

or you can define some method on the controller that resets it all, and call it during the `setupController`.  Computed properties are all marked dirty and recalculated automatically when the model behind the controller is swapped out.

```
App.FooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    //return something...
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.reset();
  }
});

App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  foo: 'asdf',
  bar: 'wert',
  reset: function(){
    this.setProperties({foo:'asdf', bar: 'ewaf'});
  }// if you want it to happen on init tack on  .on('init') right here
});
```

### on init

```
App.FooController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  foo: 'asdf',
  bar: 'wert',
  reset: function(){
    this.setProperties({foo:'asdf', bar: 'ewaf'});
  }.on('init') 
});
```

Comment: Thanks good job as always :)  
Is it a good idea to call the controller's init method if i want it to be invoked again? (my init methods calls _super() and I've no idea what Ember does inside his controller's init method)

Comment: I'd avoid calling init again, and generally I prefer creating my own method, and tacking on .on('init'), which helps avoid having to remember to call the default implementation. (example included above)